# JSF2 An action is called two times

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, action

I'm using Primefaces 4.0 (it's difficult to update it because we use an older version of IE). The JSF's library is 2.1 (Mojarra 2.1.6-FCS). This projects are running in Tomcat7 over Linux.

The problem comes when calling synchronously a rest service and its response is greater of 10 minutes.

I have an action that calls to the rest service and kept waiting for response, but before that the response will be received, my action is executed again, exactly at 5 minutes of the start of the first execution of the action

The Web aplication and Rest Service are in the same tomcat 7. And the Web App calls to Rest Service directly.

Thank you so much

my code is below

**mypage.xhtml**

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="testing" 
          actionListener="#{myBean.testing}" 
          update="@form"
     />  
</h:form>
```

**myBean.java**

```
public class EquipoBean implements Serializable {  
    public void testing() {
        log.debug("Init testing");
        String url = REST_URL+"control/sleepThread/12";
    try {
        //execute the remote call
        String response = RestClient.executeRequest(RestClient.HTTP_GET, url, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        log.debug("End testing");
    }
}
```

**restServices.java (my Rest services)**

```
@GET
 @Path("sleepThread/{minutes}")
 public String sleepThread(@PathParam("minutes") Integer minutes){
    log.debug("Init sleepThread " + minutes + " minutes");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(minutes * 60 * 1000;);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "Ok"
 }
```

Comment: You'll want to debug the issue to narrow down the search area. Open the page in Chrome and see if the browser is actually sending the second request after 5 minutes. This will tell you if the issue is with the client or the server and what the next steps should be.